# How do I set up Icecast relays so that when the main server is full listeners will be rolled over?

Tags: icecast

Running the latest version of Icecast on Centos 7 servers and replacing from Shoutcast. I currently have the main server up and operating and several relays connected and streaming the feed from the main server.

The only goal left which from what I read is possible is to set the master server and then have the other servers act as overflow when the master is full. Is there an example script somewhere because from what I see this is possible but documentation is pretty weak.

Comment: Haven't tried this, but I think you can use `fallback-when-full`, and set your fallback mount to redirect to a totally different server.  Just be sure to use a `302` status code, not a `301`, or that redirect might get cached permanently.